# Clean date property value in Alfresco CMIS api

Tags: c#, wpf, alfresco

I'm developing a WPF client that uses the Alfresco API do to some stuff.

So far so good, but I was wondering if there is a way to post to the CMIS api a null value for a specific date property. I tried sending 0, but it recognizes as "31/12/1969". If I send null or "" it returns an error saying that the value I've sent is not a valid datetime.

Here is the code... it's working for any other update, I just don't know how to clean that datetime property....

```
Dictionary<string, string> postParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>{ {"cmisaction", "update"} };
postParameters.Add("propertyId[0]", "mycustomdatetimeproperty");
postParameters.Add("propertyValue[0]", null); // ? dont know how to clean

HttpClient client = ServiceFactory.GetService(postURL);

string postURL = ServiceFactory.AlfrescoCmisApi + "browser/root?objectId=" + file.ObjectId.ToString("D") + "&succinct=true";

HttpClient client = ServiceFactory.GetService(postURL);
HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postParameters);

HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(postURL, content).Result;
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the empty date value? Could you not simply omit to send the date property if it has no value?

Comment: I want to erase the value, because I have some business logic about it, if I omit to send it will not change at all..

Comment: Any chance you could switch to using [DotCMIS](http://chemistry.apache.org/dotnet/dotcmis.html)? You can unset properties using the CMIS interface to Alfresco, and it's generally the best supported way to interact with Alfresco from external systems

Comment: Not sure, I started to make a test but realized that I don't have the Atom api enabled, and the webservice api just work with https url, with it's not my case now :/

Comment: Alfresco 4.x should support both Atom and WS for CMIS out of the box. If you upgrade to Alfresco 5, you also get the JSON binding for CMIS as well! See [this bit of the wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/CMIS#CMIS_1.1) for the URLs

Comment: The problem is that I'm not responsible for the Alfresco, just for the client that uses it's API, so, any changes in the Alfresco will take more time, it doens't depend on me

Comment: You don't need to change anything on the Alfresco side, just switch what API you talk to it through

Comment: There is a bool property for value set that you would set to false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply ommit the corresponding `propertyValue`. For example, if you only set this:

```
postParameters.Add("propertyId[0]", "mycustomdatetimeproperty");
```

But don't set a respective `propertyValue[0]`, the value will be set to `null`.